# How to create clustered hadoop environment in single machine?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to configure a clustered bigdata environment by Hadoop. i have a machine with i5 processor and 16GB Ram, in a windows 10 operating system, Or is there any way we can configure to have a same configuration for development environment for learning.

Comment: You can create a configurable amount of VMs using Vagrant https://github.com/apache/bigtop/tree/master/provisioner/vagrant

Comment: There are projects like [clusterdock](https://github.com/clusterdock), which let you run clusters in Docker for testing purposes. Note, though, that Big Data solutions like Hadoop are generally designed for use on servers, not on laptops, so your success in running clustered environments at any kind of scale will likely be limited with resources as limited as that.

Comment: 16Gb is not enough for Windows. But in you have WSL2 Docker than you can utilize your RAM consumption by HDP services in more efficient way. I would suggest you to look into my post about configuring and running HDP stack in Docker http://mixeddev.info/articles/2020/12/10/run-apache-ambari-hdp-hdf-in-docker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a single node cluster in your machine. Then docker is an option recommended by @sumitkumar But I think you're probably a beginner so this approach may not fit you well.

I suggest you install any software: `VMWare/VirtualBox` and download a `CentOS7` image file and load it to your virtual machine then install the single node cluster on it. I'm giving you an official link for Apache Hadoop Open Source Single Node Cluster installation and also if you're not willing to do too much efforts + you also want a UI for your Hadoop cluster then I'd recommend you to Setup Ambari.

(latest)  [Ambari-2.7.0](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.0.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/ch_Getting_Ready.html)
(stable)  [Ambari-2.6.2](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.2.2/bk_ambari-installation/content/ch_Getting_Ready.html)

[Hadoop Open Source](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

Comment: HDP docs are fine, but the official Ambari docs work as well https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.0

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but i want Hadoop cluster in a single machine with multiple nodes, is it possible?

Comment: @AkhilPatro Yes it is possible. Create 3 CentOS instances of 4GB ram each(meanwhile make sure your 3 node cluster must have ram size above 10 GB) doesn't matter how you do the ram partitioning. Then install your Hadoop. But it is not single node installation it is called `pseudo-distributed Hadoop cluster`

Comment: @cricket_007 The link I mentioned above, it covers Ambari installation as well. It is from Hortonworks as you can see. However, thanks for the additional information. :) Moreover, Ambari 2.7.0 contains some bugs that is why I mentioned the most stable version of Ambari

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 and Abhinav both are useful for me to learning perspective.